# meaning of "nipper" in this sentence

Tags: word-usage, sentence-meaning

The excerpt below is from Liar's Poker.  What nationality does the word "nipper" refer to? Also, is it derogatory?

> [...]he'd sell a few hundred millions worth of government bonds and grow bright again. “Yeah, Mikey!” he’d shout, as he scribbled a sales ticket. “The nippers, they love me. And I’m whipping and driving them. OOOOhhhhhhh yeaahhhh.”

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73690/discussion-on-question-by-rds80-meaning-of-nipper-in-this-sentence).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see why *child* makes no sense in the given context - it seems unlikely he was selling government bonds to young kids.

Luckily, [urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nipper) gives us an alternative meaning, indeed referring to a nationality:

> a demoralizing racial slur used to put down **people of Japanese background**. equal to calling an asian person a chink or a black person a nigger.

It's not hard to imagine the word being derived from *Nippon*, the Japanese name of Japan.

Comment: (Side note to the UD quote: a Chink is not an “Asian person”, but a _Chinese_ person. Like _Nipper_ and _Jap_, it’s based on the name of the country whose residents it describes.)

Comment: A much more common form is *nip*, of [*Private Eye* infamy](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQfNCGtQI_MQxBEfGXjHUguDEwODfWGWFb3Jt2KIakPB5E0rw_dIPsHfkA)